# From facebook login recently not getting location field

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk

I'm trying to get the location field from FB login.

I have tested before week it's working fine, but as of now i can't getting 'location' field.

Here is my code to get location and some other field:

```
$response = $fb->get('/me?fields=id,first_name,last_name,email,location');
$fbuser = $response->getDecodedBody();
echo "<pre>";print_r($fbuser);
```

and here is my response:

```
Array
(
    [id] => xxxxxxxxx
    [first_name] => John
    [last_name] => Deo
    [email] => xxxxxx@gmail.com
)
```

If anyone have an idea, please mention. Thank you!

Comment: did you check out the changelog? what about the access token, did you debug it to see if the user_location scope is missing?

Comment: `$permissions = ['email,user_location'];

$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl($redirectUrl, $permissions);`

Still not getting location

Comment: For page url,i tried to facebook.com/<id> but it's not working but instead of id from response i tried to get 'id' inside 'location' field it worked fine before week
Please help me if anyone have idea!

Comment: There is no permission named `email,user_location`

Comment: @CBroe then what i have to do for that?

Comment: Supply an array of permissions …

Comment: @CBroe i'm trying this
$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
$permissions = ['email,user_location']; // Optional permissions
$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl($redirectUrl, $permissions);

Can you please let me know what's wrong with this?

Comment: That is not an array containing several permission names as entries, but only an array with _one_ entry that contains a non-existing permission.

Comment: Can you please let me know how can i define it?